# How to get all element from div block which contains type=radio?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

maybe somebody can help me how to get all elements in Selenium in some block div with type="radio"  - For example:

I have `divBlock = By.CssSelector("input[class='Vertical Radio']");`

How to get all elements in divBlock and if element in divBlock have type="radio", click on this element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood you correctly: You want to get all child nodes from your div block, and among these you want to click the radio buttons...

here in Java, but I guess you can transform this into C# in a breeze:
you can use xpath to get all child nodes

```
By divBlock = By.CssSelector("input[class='textboxDate hasDatepicker']");
WebElement divElement = driver.findElement(divBlock);

//xpath to get all direct child nodes use "//" to get all child nodes and child of child nodes
String xpathExpression = "./*";
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression));

for(WebElement element : elements) {
    if(element.getAttribute("type").equals("radio")) {
        element.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
foreach(var elem in driver.FindElement(divBlock).FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@type='radio']")))
{
     elem.Click();
}
```